# MTM has a test agent in "Ready" status, but can't connect

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

So here's my setup: Visual Studio/Microsoft Test Manager (2012) running on Windows Server 2008 (running on a virtual machine), trying to connect to another VM running Windows 8 (not 8.1). The issue is that in Lab Manager, it says that my Win 8 VM is in a "Ready" status, but when I go to connect, it says "Microsoft Environment Viewer could not connect to the machine..." I have looked for this error and nothing that I can find applies to this error. I get a somewhat generic "how to" doc from MS in most of my searching, but it's not helping me here. The interesting thing about it is that I can connect via the remote desktop option...So I don't know where to go from here. If it's a firewall issue, I don't know what to look for exactly. There may be some detail I've missed, but I don't know what it could be...help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I have found the answer, and it is [here](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2011/06/01/cannot-connect-to-a-lab-management-environment-using-the-mtm-environment-viewer.aspx). Basically, you have to reduce somewhat the security of your environment to allow RDP Clients that aren't the same version as the host OS expects to run.